# adding time in seconds to hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to extract the hour, minutes and seconds from the date in variable `e` (1:25:40). Then add to the hour in the variable `d`("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00").
Expected effect:

`21: 25: 38` +`5140 seconds` = `22: 51: 18`

`var d` + `var w` = `22: 51: 18`

```
var d = new Date("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00");
//hour --> 21:25:38

var e = new Date("2019-06-29T 1:25:40.000+00:00");
```

I want '1: 25: 40' to count as 1h 25 min 40 seconds

1h ---> 3600 seconds

25 min --> 1500 seconds

40 seconds

Result:
`21:25:38` + `1: 25: 40` = `22:51:18`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
var d = new Date("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00");
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 5140);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `new_d = new Date(d.getTime() + 5140 * 1000)`

Given `var d = new Date("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00")`, my output is `2019-06-29T22:51:18.000Z` for `new_d`.

The reason that this works is because `.getTime()` returns a long which represents the number of milliseconds since midnight on Thursday, January 1, 1970 ([there's a fun history behind this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). You can also pass a Unix-time long into the `Date()` constructor to get a new time object, so if you can express your offset in terms of seconds, multiply that value by 1000, add it to your original long, and you're good to go.